# Ubuntu: Terminal remove part of string

Tags: bash, shell, csv, ubuntu, terminal

I want to use the Ubuntu Terminal to rename several hundred files in a folder since I am not allowed to install anything.

The name of the files is in the following format:
ER201703_Company_Name_Something_9876543218_90087625374823.csv
Afterwards it should look like this:
ER201703_9876543218_90087625374823.csv

So, I want to remove the  middle part (Company_name_something) which sometimes has 2, 3 or even 4 _'s. I wanted to create 2 strings; one for the front part and one for the back part. The front part is easy and already working but I am struggeling with the back part.

```
for name in *.csv;
do
    charleng=${#name};
    start=$(echo "$name" | grep -a '_9');
    back=$(echo "$name" | cut -c $start-);
    front=$(echo "$name" | cut -c1-9);  
    mv "$name""$front$back";
done
```

I am trying to find the position of _9 and keep everything from there to the end of the string.

Best regards
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `rename` is installed (I think that's the case for Ubuntu) you can use the following command instead of your loop.

```
rename -n 's/^(ER\d*)\w*?(_9\w*)/$1$2/' *.csv
```

Remove the `-n` (*no act*) to apply the changes.

#### Explanation

- `s/.../.../` substitutes matches of the left regex with the right pattern.
- `(ER\d*)` matches the first part (`ER` followed by some digits) and stores it inside `$1` for later use.
- `\w*?` matches the company part, that is as few (non-greedy) word characters (letters, numbers, underscore, ...) as possible.
- `(_9\w*)` matches the second part and stores it inside `$2` for later use.
- `$1$2` is the substitution of the previously matched parts. We only omit the company part.

Comment: Wow! That was easier and more understandable than expected! Thank you very much!

Comment: or, if you know the part to be removed contains only letters, and the remaining part starts with something else, like a number, something like `rename -n "s/_[a-zA-Z_]+_/_/"` would also do.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'_' '{printf "mv %s %s_%s_%s\n",$0,$1,$(NF-1),$NF}'
```

Example:

```
kent$  awk -F'_' '{printf "mv %s %s_%s_%s\n",$0,$1,$(NF-1),$NF}' <<<"ER201703_Company_Name_Something_9876543218_90087625374823.csv"                                         
mv ER201703_Company_Name_Something_9876543218_90087625374823.csv ER201703_9876543218_90087625374823.csv
```

This one-liner will print out the `mv old new` command. If it is ok, you just pipe the output to `|sh`, (`awk ....|sh`),  the rename will be done.

If your filename can contain spaces, pls consider to quote the filenames by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer alternative solution, may be more generic.

```
rename 's/^([^_]+(?=_))(?:\w+(?=_\d+))(_\d+_\d+\.csv)$/$1$2/' *.csv
```

in a case the name of the log will change you want to have robust regex expression.

```
([^_]+(?=_)) - match everything that not underscore till the first one and store it to $1
(?:\w+(?=_\d+)) - match chars until the numbers but (?:...) not store to var
(_\d+_\d+\.csv) -  match set of numbers and file extension and store it to $2
```